# Is a cyclic group considered a more specialized form of a "plain-ole" group?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, cyclic-groups

(edited question)
I'm trying to identify (for context) the hierarchy of groups, rings and fields and then where cyclic groups "fit". For example, I've seen groups represented at the top of the hierarchy, then rings, then fields. I'm wondering if a cyclic group is considered to be in the category--groups or its own separate category?

(original question)
I'm trying to get a high level view of groups, rings and fields and then within fields cyclic groups and I'm wondering if a cyclic group is considered to be in the family of just plain-ole groups?

Comment: The cyclic groups are about the most vanilla groups there are.

Comment: I changed "algebraic group" to "group" in your title, because "algebraic group" (probably unexpectedly and counter-intuitively) refers to a more complicated object... not just "groups in the context of abstract algebra". You might see Wikipedia's entry for "algebraic group" to see something about it... in any case that it's not what you meant. :)

Comment: Its nice to have someone else tell you, dictating to you, what you meant, isnt it @JohnGalt? And derailing your question in the process. Instead of asking you first what you might have meant and allowing you to elaborate.  Have I ever mentioned the pretentiousness from contributors on this site? I think I have. Countless times.

Comment: I appreciate the comments, I'm such a neophyte in all of this I assumed groups were always associated with some type of algebra, but now I know better. :)

Comment: @CogitoErgoCogitoSum, I'm sorry, do you think that my edit and comment are inaccurate? I made that edit in good faith, explaining my rationale in the comment and my self-esteem is not tied to it, so I'm open to any argument in favor of a different interpretation of the situation.

Comment: I didnt say you were wrong. I said you dictated to someone else what their intentions were instead of having the human decency to simply ask and point out your confusion.  YOU were the one confused by the wording, not the questioner. So why fault the questioner when YOU could have asked for elaboration?  You say your ego isnt tied to it but it clearly is; it didnt even cross your mind that maybe you didnt know what you were talking about but that the other person didnt.  I dont know. Does it make sense to criticize someone else when youre the one confused? You tell me?

Comment: @CogitoErgoCogitoSum, after considering whether the questioner might conceivably have truly meant "algebraic group", it became clear from the rest of the question that this was not the case. Over the years, I have heard similarly mis-formed questions about "algebraic groups", so this was not utterly surprising. I have also found that people asking such mis-formed questions do not understand what they've accidentally referenced, so are usually not able to confirm or deny a proposed clarification. That's the very problem. I wasn't confused, as this is a very familiar scenario...

Comment: @paulgarrett Wikipedia (which could be wrong) starts each definition of group, ring, and field as an algebraic structure. Are you saying that a group is not an algebraic structure or that it can be an algebraic structure but that's a specific instance of a more generic designation of group, ring, or field, or something completely different?

Comment: It's a fussy issue about (very standard) terminology. Groups, rings, fields, are indeed all algebraic structures. But the phrase "algebraic group" has a well-established meaning that is much more complicated than "a group, which is an algebraic structure". Very roughly, an "algebraic group" is a "functor" (a kind of mapping) from commutative rings to groups, for example the "algebraic group (functor)" $GL_2$ applied to a commutative ring $R$ gives $GL_2(R)$, the group of invertible 2-by-2 matrices with entries in $R$. I agree that this is an unfortunate terminology, but it is standard by now.

Comment: @paulgarrett at least at this point I see where I went "off the rails" and can further understand how that would be confusing to mix the two without at least clarifying that I'm not referring to the much more complicated version of algebraic group. Again as someone trying to teach an old dog new tricks, I find it helpful to have the equivalent of "you are here" for context when taking a deep dive into what is for me new math...and that was the basis for my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every cyclic group is a group but not every group is a cyclic group.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, a cyclic group is a group.

Answer (score 1):

Cyclic groups are groups, but they're nice because they're easy to think about (they can be visualized as, say, a cycle), are abelian, and have plenty of other nice properties that always hold no matter the order.